# programmatically invoking a break point

Tags: rust

In rust is there any way to break into the debugger. C# has DebugBreak which when executed simply behaves the same way as though a break point was set there.

Breaking on panic I know how to do and thats not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's [`::std::intrinsics::breakpoint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.breakpoint.html) (unstable/feature-gated, so only available on nightly Rust):

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

use ::std::intrinsics::breakpoint;

fn main() {
    unsafe { breakpoint() };
}
```

Comment: @pm100:  Why?  All calls to foreign code are unsafe, as they could do absolutely anything to memory in violation of Rust’s safety guarantees.

Comment: It’s not an arbitrary call to some foo function, its a function provided by rust.

Comment: @pm100: It’s an intrinsic provided by Rust in order to invoke behaviour outside of Rust’s control.

Comment: Just like all io then, function calls provided by rust that call behavior outside rusts control

Comment: @pm100: And calling those functions directly from Rust is indeed unsafe, but Rust provides safe wrappers around them based on their assumed conformance to specification.  By contrast, there’s absolutely no specification of what a debugger will do once a breakpoint is triggered: it can manipulate memory in any manner it likes.